# Generating wakeup and Error frame In LIN bus using CAPL script in Canoe tool

Tags: automated-tests, capl, canoe, automotive

Trying to generate LIN Slave wakeup frame from CAPL script in which I need to simulate below condition

1. System is in sleep.
2. My Node Connected to ECU will wakeup with three 250us pulse (LIN slave wakeup frame on Bus not 999us neither wakeup frame through 0x3C).
3. Send Diagnostic frame to my ECU with Checksum Error
4. send Unconditional frame to my ECU to get response from my ECU whether previous frame checksum Error is detected or not .
   5.Again send diagnostic frame to my ECU with checksum Error
5. Again send Unconditional frame to get ECU response for checksum Error Detection.
6. put system in Sleep again.

Repeat 1 to 7 step  to check same thing multiple times .

I need to support that anybody know how we can do this as i am able to generate checksum error but not able to generate LIN slave wakeup frame on bus through CAPL script.

its a sequence for one test case that I need to generate to check my LIN driver , as we got some issues from Client side and my LIN driver is failing in their test cases but client cant give their environment for testing (Automotive vehicle manufacturer confidential tools and environment).

Thanks

I tried t generate 250 us pulse through CAPL inbuild LIN function but after checking on Logic level of bus I cant see any pulses